# How to manage flow of non logged in users and allow a select few to create accounts (password protecting a page)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app where most of the users should never log in. I also use this same app for a small selection of users that I personally manage and would like to allow them to create a Firebase account, preferably just with by giving them a password to access the account creation page. Ideally I don't want just anyone to be able to create an account, only those who I have personally given access to. Is there a way I could password protect the account creation page so that only those with access to the password could create an account? Perhaps there is another way to do this? Ideally, I'm not looking to get into a situation where anyone can create an account and then downstream I have to authorize that account so that it has the correct access. I really just want only those with the access upstream to be able to create the account. Perhaps this is not logical but this seems to make more sense than letting accounts be created by anyone and then approved by me after the fact.  So my question really is, how do I password protect a page in flutter? Or is this just a bad idea and should I work to manage things downstream? Or is there another solution I have yet to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using something like a dynamic link that navigates to the specified page in the app when clicked. [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) might be of help. Only those who have the link will be able to access it and I presume that you could manage the link actions from the Firebase console.

You could also opt for simplicity and create a password field that pops up before your account creation page

Comment: Dynamic links seems like a great way to go. Seems this would be cleaner overall on presentation than the password route which while simpler isn't as elegant.  Thanks for your help.